# How to import semi-structured data into neo4j by py2neo

Tags: python-2.7, csv, neo4j, py2neo

I have 200 CSV files and I want to import them to neo4j; the data are stored in all kinds of tables in CSV, meaning, different structures of tables storing same type of data. They are like:

Table 1

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
```

Table 2

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
```

Table 3

```
    A     B     C
D d1 d2 d1 d2 d1 d2
```

I know I can write script using for loop and if statement to match the key words, But I'm wondering if there is any better way or tools?

I've seen people suggesting using Hadoop MapReduce technique to handle unstructured data; not sure if it is suitable for semi-structured data?

Has anyone known how to process this kinda of data and import to neo4j by python or py2neo?

Comment: Very difficult to answer without an idea how you want to structure your graph, i.e. what are the nodes and edges in your table.

Comment: Agree with Martin. You need to first give some thought to how your graph will be structured before an answer to your question can be determined. Once you have done this, a Cypher LOAD CSV statement will probably prove useful.